# Why must a std::ranges::filter_view object be non-const for querying its elements?

Tags: c++, constants, standards, c++20, std-ranges

```
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::literals;

int main()
{
    auto fn_is_l = [](auto const c) { return c == 'l'; };

    {
        auto v = "hello"sv | std::views::filter(fn_is_l);
        std::cout << *v.begin() << std::endl; // ok
    }

    {
        auto const v = "hello"sv | std::views::filter(fn_is_l);
        std::cout << *v.begin() << std::endl; // error
    }
}
```

See: https://godbolt.org/z/vovvT19a5

```
<source>:18:30: error: passing 'const std::ranges::filter_view<
                       std::basic_string_view<char>, main()::
                       <lambda(auto:15)> >' as 'this' argument discards
                       qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   18 |         std::cout << *v.begin() << std::endl; // error
      |                       ~~~~~~~^~
In file included from <source>:1:/include/c++/11.1.0/ranges:1307:7: 
     note: in call to 'constexpr std::ranges::filter_view<_Vp, 
           _Pred>::_Iterator std::ranges::filter_view<_Vp, Pred>
           ::begin() [with _Vp = std::basic_string_view<char>; _Pred =
           main()::<lambda(auto:15)>]'
 1307 |       begin()
      |       ^~~~~
```

**Why must a** `std::ranges::filter_view` **object be non-const for querying its elements?**

Comment: Have you tried using `cbegin()` instead?

Comment: no `cbegin` member for a `std::ranges::view` object by default.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In order to provide the amortized constant time complexity required by `range`, `filter_view::begin` caches the result in `*this`. This modifies the internal state of `*this` and thus cannot be done in a `const` member function.

Comment: That's curious if the result with or without the cache can be guaranteed to be the same. (Can it?) then mutable is an option right? const is all about the external api to an object not the internal state.  It is non trivial to use mutable keyword correctly but it can be done.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Right, technically this is possible, but this requires thread synchronization (to meet the requirement for `const` functions), which is deemed too expensive.

Comment: Is it not allowed to do the caching on a per-thread basis?

Comment: @dan04 - that no longer meets the time complexity requirements, at least from a pedantic point of view.

Comment: Why can't it do the initial search in the constructor of the `filter_view`? That would allow `const` begin/end functions as constant time operations, but it does mean that the constructor is no longer constant time...

Comment: FYI: [P0789R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0789r3.pdf) 1.3.1 "The filter adaptor is not const-iterable" explains the design decision of `filter_view`.

Comment: You wouldn't think the thread synchronization would be _that_ expensive (just a `std::atomic_flag` to indicate whether the cached value has been populated; if that's unset, then use the expensive locking).

Comment: That said, if you want a filter view that's a range, you can just take a copy.

Answer (score 7):

The time complexity requirement here comes from the description of `filter_view::begin()` in  [[range.filter.view]](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.filter.view#5):

> `constexpr iterator begin();`
>
> *Returns*: `{*this, ranges​::​find_­if(base_­, ref(*pred_­))}`.
>
> *Remarks*: In order to provide the amortized constant time complexity required by the `range` concept when `filter_­view` models
> `forward_­range`, this function caches the result within the
> `filter_­view` for use on subsequent calls.

That is to say, the implementation needs to internally cache the iterator found by `ranges​::​find_if` that satisfies the predicate, which allows each subsequent call to `begin()` to simply return the cached value in constant time, just like [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/ranges#L1559) does:

```
template<input_range _Vp, indirect_unary_predicate<iterator_t<_Vp>> _Pred>
class filter_view : public view_interface<filter_view<_Vp, _Pred>> {
  _Vp _M_base = _Vp();
  __box<_Pred> _M_pred;
  _CachedPosition<_Vp> _M_cached_begin;

public:
  // ...
  constexpr _Iterator
  begin() {
    if (_M_cached_begin._M_has_value())
      return {this, _M_cached_begin._M_get(_M_base)};
   
    auto __it = ranges::find_if(_M_base, std::ref(*_M_pred));
    _M_cached_begin._M_set(_M_base, __it);
    return {this, std::move(__it)};
  }
};
```

Since it needs to set the cache value inside `filter_view` when calling `begin()` for the first time, this makes the `begin()` unable to be `const`-qualified.

It is worth noting that other range adaptors with similar time complexity requirements include [`drop_view`](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.adaptors#range.drop.view-4), [`drop_while_view`](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.adaptors#range.drop.while.view-5), [`split_view`](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.adaptors#range.split.view-4), [`reverse_view`](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.adaptors#range.reverse.view-3), and C++23's [`chunk_by_view`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2443r1.html#pnum_7).

Among them, `drop_while_view`, `split_view` and `chunk_by_view` are *never* const-iterable, because they do not have a const-qualified `begin()`, just like `filter_view`.

Comment: That's really helpful, particularly the list of other similar classes.  Thank you for this.