# Why does std::filter_view not have a way to eagerly evaluate it and convert it to view whose begin in const?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

`filter_view` [does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67667318/why-must-a-stdrangesfilter-view-object-be-non-const-for-querying-its-element) have a const begin.

But I wonder why isn't there a member or free function on it that would return some_filter_view  type that is that is same as filter_view except it has a const begin(). Obviously this method would be O(n), but it would be fine since it is explicit in code.

Is it just that it is too much work to standardize/ too big of a compile slowdown, or are there other reasons?

Basic example of what I would want:

```
void fn(){
    std::array<int,5> arr{1,2,3,4,5};
    const auto filtered = arr | std::views::filter([](auto){return true;});
    filtered.begin(); // does not compile
    // --would be nice if we could do 
    // const auto filtered = arr | std::views::filter([](auto){return true;}) | eval_begin;
    // --now filtered.begin() can be called
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically "why can't we have a `filter_view` that caches on construction".

The answer is that it will make copies O(N) since the cached iterator are iterators into the original view, so your copied view have to find `begin()` again for its copy.

If you have a (non-const) `filter_view` already, then it's trivial to make a const-iterable view out of it with `subrange`. Obvious this requires the `filter_view` to be kept alive while the `subrange` is.

Comment: why are cached iterators iterators into the view and not into original data?

Comment: `filter_view<V, F>` adapts some arbitrary view `V`. It can only cache `V`'s iterators.

Comment: I still don't get why that would make copy O(n)...  but probably my understanding of view implementation is too naive.

Comment: The general rule is that an iterator into some view `v` isn't an iterator into a copy of `v`.  This is true for containers, and it remains true for views.